# getElementByID.innerHTML is failing to change text

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and Javascript and I decided to try write a basic shopping cart.

I have a problem though. Why doesent this:

```
    if(totalItems == 0)
{

  document.getElementById('yourCartContains').innerHTML = "Your cart contains no items!";   
}
```

Change this:

```
<b id = "yourCartContains">0</b>
```

To say  "your cart contains no items" instead of 0?

The function definitely works, because I have tried switching the function to show an `alert` and it does this without any problems - so function works, but for some reason the function does not change the text.

Here is the function with the alert (I even changed totalItems to 0 to prove function is being called):

```
var totalItems = 0;
if(totalItems == 0)
{
  alert("Random Alert is called upon function being executed");
  document.getElementById('yourCartContains').innerHTML = "Your cart contains no items!";   <!-- But this isnt -->
}
```

I am debugging in chrome.

Comment: Is `totalItems` definitely equal to 0 (or falsey, for that matter)? When is this code being executed?

Comment: Yes,totalItems is definitely equal to zero, and the function is being executed, but for some reason the text is not changing.

Comment: Can you post the whole function, with that alert included? I'm tempted to vote offtopic because asking "why my code doesn't work" without posting the necessary code

Comment: @Pablo Sure thing, just a second

Comment: I'm with @Pablo here. http://jsfiddle.net/4zk26gd4/ works, meaning your error is in code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Should work unless: totalItems isn't equal to 0. IMHO you should better do something like <b><span id='whatever'></span></b>. Better would be to use CSS directly on the id #whatever {font-weight: bold}

Comment: Thats very strange. I've posted both the yourCartContains id in HTML and the function which definitely is being executed. What else could it be? @SBI

Comment: have you checked no other code is modifying that <b> content?

Comment: Is anything being shown in the logging console? In Firefox, you can bring this up by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+K.

Comment: I will add function with alert to the question.

Comment: Next time edit the question, don't add code in comments ;)

Comment: Do you have two elements with id = `yourCartContains`?

Comment: @SBI I tried using the function in JSFiddle and it worked when I took the <script> tags away. However if I used <script> tags it would not edit the text.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementByID().innerHTML` definitely works.

Make sure:

- `document` refers to the same document the element is in (you're not working with an iframe or such).
- you call the function when the element is attached to the DOM.

  This [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/bhjdyny5/):

  ```
  <script>document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'bar';</script>
  <b id="foo"></b>
  ```

  This [works](http://jsfiddle.net/bhjdyny5/1/):

  ```
  <b id="foo"></b>
  <script>document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'bar';</script>
  ```
- your html is valid. It could be that invalid markup doesn't let your browser find the correct element.

Anyway, if you're working in chrome, you really should debug with the console and not with "alerts". Press <kbd>F12</kbd> (on Windows / Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Mac. If there are any errors, you should see them in red in the console tab.

If there are no errors, do this:

```
if(totalItems == 0)
{
  console.log('el: ', document.getElementById('yourCartContains'));
  document.getElementById('yourCartContains').innerHTML = "Your cart contains no items!";   <!-- But this isnt -->
}
```

and see what your console tells you. (There probably will be an `el: undefined`)

Comment: I tried using the function in JSFiddle and it worked when I took the <script> tags away. However if I used <script> tags it would not edit the text. @Roman

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Have you loaded your script after your html?

```
<html>
    <head>


        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><b id = "yourCartContains">0</b></div>


        <script>

           var totalItems = 0;
if(totalItems == 0)
{
  alert("Random Alert is called upon function being executed");
  document.getElementById('yourCartContains').innerHTML = "Your cart contains no items!";   <!-- But this isnt -->
} 


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var totalItems = 0;
    if(totalItems == 0)
    {document.getElementById('yourCartContains').innerHTML = "Your cart contains no items!";}
  </script>
<span id="yourCartContains" style="font-weight:bold"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have very painful experience using text to innerHTML.
Since my text contains a lot of dynamic element (select2 for searching option list) and I forgot to put ending quote . The text looks fine, in some cases, however, the innerHTML truncate the "submit" button is missing.
The text assigned to innerHTML is translate to other strange result automatically. if HTML syntax is not correct, it produces very weird string in innerHTML. the problem is intermittent, some case is fine, some are not good. Since project is big, I wasted whole night effort to fight to bug.

I finally figure a way to debug the dynamic element by using W3 validator (https://validator.w3.org/nu). copy and paste into a file and check the dynamic element syntax. There are some online HTML checker (https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html).